# Export SQLite to Excel occur an exception

Tags: java, android, excel, sqlite

I'm using a library SQLite2XL (https://github.com/androidmads/SQLite2XL) to export SQLite to a file in xls but the program show an exception.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/TableExcel.xls (Permission denied)

```
public void exportToExcel(){
        //sqlite2xl
        SQLiteToExcel sqLiteToExcel = new SQLiteToExcel(this, "dataUser.db");
        sqLiteToExcel.exportSingleTable("data", "TableExcel.xls", new SQLiteToExcel.ExportListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Start exporting...");
            }
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(String filePath) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exporting to excel done in " + filePath);
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error occur " + e);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: did you mentioned this --> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in manifest?

Comment: Yes, I put that permission on manifest
Do you think that could be another permission?
Because in exception appear Permission Denied

Comment: try this --> go to device's settings, apps, your_app, then choose permissions from there. Allow the permissions. and give read permission also in manifest

Comment: Well the storage permission was off, but how can I put these permission on in code?

Comment: did you achived your target after turning on your device permission?what permission did you turned on manually?

Comment: Yes, after I turn on storage permission I could export SQLite to xls file
I turn on storage

Comment: what permission did you turned on manually?

Comment: storage permission